# Ubuntu user uid confusion for nobody user 65534

Tags: linux, user-accounts, ubuntu-server

Hello Linux/Ubuntu community,

I have a strange issue on a new Ubuntu 20.04 linux server. In my server I have modified the user nobody to be uid 99 without a problem, ensured there was no process held by this user. However after I changed the UID of nobody user to 99, the `getent` command gives some strange answers as below.

```
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#sudo getent passwd nobody
nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#sudo getent passwd 65534 
nobody:*:65534:65534:User Nobody:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#grep nobody: /etc/passwd
nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#grep nobody: /etc/group 
nobody:x:99:
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#grep 65534 /etc/group
nogroup:x:65534:
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#ls -l /bin/false
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39256 Sep  5  2019 /bin/false
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#sudo useradd -u 65534 -s /bin/false oldnobody
useradd: UID 65534 is not unique
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#ps -u 65534
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
vijay@nortis:/home/vijay#
```

I am unable to add a new user with that UID. Are there other places where UID can be fixed invisible.  There is nothing in the shadow file either. Very puzzling.  Could this be one of `systemd` effects?  Any help or input from Linux experts or Ubuntu experts will be very helpful in resolving this.

Comment: Got an [nscd](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nscd/nscd.8) daemon running?

Comment: No pretty sure of that at least. reminds of scary solaris days though..